# Preloading pages while virtual scrolling is enabled in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I am currently working on a jqGrid application which uses virtual scrolling (scroll: 1), and I must say it works fantastically! However, I have noticed that in certain cases (for example a large 10 column table with 50 rows per page) there can be a delay in loading the page as the server is sending about 6 kilobytes of data each request. I've been thinking about a way to minimize this and to prevent any inconvenience for the client, and thought that by preloading the page before and after the current page, the client could scroll with minimal interference.

Of course there is not much to be done about delay when the user scrolls to another location by dragging and dropping the scrolling, but if he is using the up and down arrows to scroll, I would like to implement the system I mentioned above.

So really, I was wondering if anyone had ever implemented such a system? I know the virtual scrolling function automatically unloads the pages as you scroll off them, but perhaps someone has found a way to go around this? Or at least has some tips to offer?

Thank you.